# Google Sheets, Apps Script, How to use Range.autoFill() for values only?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with work hours, that each month I create a new copy of, and then fix it for the new month. The sheet has a table, with a border, where the first column is the date. So I enter the first day of the month on the top cell of the column, and then, to fill the entire column, I use:

```
  var firstDate = newSheet.getRange("B5");    
  var dateColumn = newSheet.getRange("B5:B35");    
  firstDate.autoFill(dateColumn, SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
```

This works nicely, incrementing the date, but the problem is that it copies the formatting of the first cell, which is the top left corner of the table, to all other cells in the column.

Is there a way to use autoFill() so that it only copies the values without the formatting?

I also tried using:

```
 firstDate.copyTo(dateColumn, {contentsOnly:true});
```

and it copies just the values without the formatting, but does not increment the dates.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, how about copying the text styles and background colors of the cells "B6:B35", and after `autoFill` was done, how about pasting them? If this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
var firstDate = newSheet.getRange("B5");
var dateColumn = newSheet.getRange("B5:B35");
var range = dateColumn.offset(1, 0, dateColumn.getNumRows() - 1);
var styles = range.getTextStyles();
var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
firstDate.autoFill(dateColumn, SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
range.setTextStyles(styles).setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
```

#### Note:

- If you want to keep other parameters except for the text styles and background colors, please add them to the above script.
- If you want to clear the cell format to the default format, you can also use the following modification.

  ```
    var firstDate = newSheet.getRange("B5");
    var dateColumn = newSheet.getRange("B5:B35");
    firstDate.autoFill(dateColumn, SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
    dateColumn.offset(1, 0, dateColumn.getNumRows() - 1).clearFormat();
  ```

#### References:

- [getTextStyles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getTextStyles())
- [getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> It didn't solve my problem because the issue I have is with the cells borders, which are not part of the text style or backgrounds. Here is what the result looks like now:

When I saw your provided image, I could understand your situation. In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
var firstDate = newSheet.getRange("B5");
var dateColumn = newSheet.getRange("B5:B35");
var range = dateColumn.offset(1, 0, dateColumn.getNumRows() - 1);
var border = range.getBorder().getLeft();
var color = border.getColor().asRgbColor();
var style = border.getBorderStyle();
firstDate.autoFill(dateColumn, SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
dateColumn.offset(1, 0, dateColumn.getNumRows() - 1).clearFormat().setBorder(null, true, null, null, null, null, color, style);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It didn't solve my problem because the issue I have is with the cells borders, which are not part of the text style or backgrounds. Here is what the result looks like now:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17sO5l_NAGH0m4n0WTKGpbE3lXVf_bOX1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @yuvals Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your provided image, I could understand your situation. So I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: Yep, that does the trick. The lower-left corner is still wrong, but I see how to fix it now. The range.getBorder() function is not documented on the official developers.google.com site or anywhere else. What type of Object is it returning? This is getting really interesting. Thanks a million.

Comment: @yuvals Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `but I see how to fix it now. The range.getBorder() function is not documented on the official developers.google.com site or anywhere else. What type of Object is it returning?`, in this case, I think that `getBorder` returns the object of Borders. But unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that this has not been added to the official document of Class Range yet. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) I apologize for this.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for your help.
I decided that the elegant solution to the border problem is to add an empty row before the first day and after the last day, so all the rows I autoFill() are the same.

Comment: @yuvals Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. But I think that my answer might be useful for other users. So I would like to leave my answer. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: Hey @Tanaike, you have nothing to apologize for - you did nothing wrong. I learned from you about the getBorder() function. Thank you for that.